# How to determine if a given String is part of a group?

Tags: grouping

Very new to programming here. I am attempting to make a method that determines if the users input is part of a group of variables. For example:

User input is "C"

If "C" is found from a group containing the letters "C Db E Fb G Ab B", then print "true".

But, I want it to print "false" if user input is "D", because the D needs to be paired with "b".

How to achieve this? Here is what I have tried but obviously it doesn't work since it doesn't understand that some letters need to be paired with another letter:

```
// Check the Scale Project



import java.util.Scanner;

public class Hiekkalaatikko {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner skanneri = new Scanner(System.in);

    String I = String.valueOf(skanneri.nextLine());     //asking for the values
    String II = String.valueOf(skanneri.nextLine());
    String III = String.valueOf(skanneri.nextLine());

    checker(I, II, III);    // sending the values to method

    }

        public static void checker(String I, String II, String III) {

        String DbScale = "Db_Eb_F_Gb_Ab_Bb_C"; // If input is found from this group, then print C major

        if (DbScale.contains(I) && DbScale.contains(II) && DbScale.contains(III)) {
            System.out.println("Db major");
        }
    }
}
```